# How to fix errors on standard headers in VisualStudio 2017 (on Windows 10) building a .dll - file for Windows XP

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on a .dll - file that I will use for a program that is supposed to run on Windows XP. I am using VisualStudio 2017 on a Windows 10 machine for this and I want to build the project, consisting of all the necessary code for the .dll - file, thereby targetting Windows XP (64Bit).

Building the project for Windows 10 is no problem, I will show the settings I have selected for that below.
Trying to build with XP(64 Bit) as target, I get the following errors (a picture follows shortly):

Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'processthreadsapi.h': No such file or directory

Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "ip2string.h"
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "processthreadsapi.h"

Here are the configurations I have altered in both cases:

[Windows 10 setup, build works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP0i9.png)

[Windows XP setup, producing the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsxGv.png)

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmyjh.png)

I've already read

---> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=vs-2017

and installed the apparently needed c++ runtime support, it still doesn't work. I am aware of choosing the Visual Studio 2015 toolsets.. I read multiple times about lacking support for the 2017 versions and people fixing their errors by choosing the 2015 option (choosing 2017 xp actually results in a few more errors in my case), which why I also tried it that way.
I would appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you choose the XP toolset, Visual Studio uses a different include path with files from a older XP compatible version of the Windows SDK.

If you look at the functions defined in ip2string.h, the minimum version supported is Windows 7. I would imagine processthreadapi.h is an attempt at refactoring Windows.h and therefore isn't available in the XP SDK.

If you look at processthreadapi.h you will notice it is almost al guarded by

```
#pragma region Application Family or OneCore Family
```

Without seeing the code I am not sure exactly how to fix your problem, but I would suggest you try and use Windows.h everywhere instead of specific API includes.